# trouble passing argument for output$arg in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

The code below works when it is not in a function:

```
inputdf <- s %>%
filter(status == 'Open', next_step_action != 'Comment') %>%
arrange(desc(created_date)) %>%
select(link,
       age,
       assignee,
       next_step,
       title,
       description,
       created_date,
       update_date,
       tags)

output$assigndt = DT::renderDataTable(inputdf,
                                    options = list(paging = FALSE, autoWidth = TRUE),
                                    escape = FALSE)
```

The above runs just fine. 
if I try to turn this into a function, I can't figure out how to use an argument for output$assigndt:

```
  dtconfig <- function(inputdf, op){
inputdf <- s %>%
  filter(status == 'Open', next_step_action != 'Comment') %>%
  arrange(desc(created_date)) %>%
  select(link,
         age,
         assignee,
         next_step,
         title,
         description,
         created_date,
         update_date,
         tags)

output$op = DT::renderDataTable(inputdf,
                                      options = list(paging = FALSE, autoWidth = TRUE),
                                      escape = FALSE)
}

dtconfig(assigned, assigndt)
```

The inputdf arg works, but the op argument does not work.  How do I pass an argument to output$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you posted a *complete* example, so that we can conveniently try.

What about doing

```
output$op <<- DT::renderDataTable.....
```

instead of

```
output$op = DT::renderDataTable.....
```

in your function? Does that work? `<<-` is the non-local assignment. I'm not sure this is correct, though.

Otherwise, you can probably do:

```
dtconfig <- function(inputdf, op){
s %>%
  filter(status == 'Open', next_step_action != 'Comment') %>%
  arrange(desc(created_date)) %>%
  select(link,
         age,
         assignee,
         next_step,
         title,
         description,
         created_date,
         update_date,
         tags)
}

output$op <- DT::renderDataTable(dtconfig(assigned, assigndt),
                                      options = list(paging = FALSE, autoWidth = TRUE),
                                      escape = FALSE)
```

But I'm not sure, since I don't know what are `s`, `assigned`, etc. Hope this works.